# Android app that display different layouts at same time with hdmi

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, hdmi

I want to create an app, that will display different layout on phone and different layout on display connected with HDMI. First layout will display just controls and some info and layout on HDMI connected display will display things like photo or video or maybe photo with user defined text. I want this app to work without root. I know that it is possible because mxplayer works familiar to what I want.

When HDMI is connected on the phone it automatically adapt video to my television and controls are visible just on phone. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the "onCreate"-Method of an activity you can set the layout. So you have first to check if HDMI is connected. If so just load the other layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this. Some device manufacturers may have options for this for their specific hardware -- for example, I seem to recall that HTC offers something for this.